# How to send card response for outgoing webhook in microsoft teams

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

[This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook) said I could use **card/image/mention** response using outgoing webhook but there is no example other than simple reply.

I also tried [json response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using)

But my bot says

```
Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request
```

[This works!](https://docs.cognigy.com/docs/deploy-an-microsoft-teams-endpoint)

Any other examples...?

Comment: Could you please try this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-outgoing-webhook)?Try if that works

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT thank you!